# How to Catch Hover and Mouse Leave Signal In PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

QPushButton has a signal which is named `clicked()`, and we can catch click events through it. Is there a method or signal which catches hover and leave events?

How can I catch mouse-over button and mouse-leave button, like this:

```
button = QPushButton(window)
button.clicked.connect(afunction)
```

Note: I use python3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to subclass the `QPushButton` class and reimplement the `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent`:

```
class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        # other initializations...

    def enterEvent(self, QEvent):
        # here the code for mouse hover
        pass

    def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
        # here the code for mouse leave
        pass
```

You can then handle the event locally, or emit a signal (if other widgets needs to react on this event you could use a signal to notify the event to other widgets).