# PyQt5 - Hover signal for QPushButton created via Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt

I just created my first PyQt app used to store personnal data. 
On the New Entry Dialog there is a button that when clicked, fills in QLineEdits with default values.
I would like to implement a feature so that when the mouse cursor hovers this Default button, you get a preview (probably via setPlaceholderText) of what the QLineEdits will be set to.

After looking around for a solution I came across this solution : [How to Catch Hover and Mouse Leave Signal In PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678624/how-to-catch-hover-and-mouse-leave-signal-in-pyqt5)
to subclass the PushButton and reimplement enterEvent and leaveEvent.

However I have created my GUI with Qt Designer and am a bit confused as to how I can apply this solution since the QPushButton is created inside the Designer's .ui file where I can't really make changes...

Here's an extract of the .ui file when converted to .py with pyuic5

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")

        self.pushButton_contact_defaut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_client)
        self.pushButton_contact_defaut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 165, 22))
        self.pushButton_contact_defaut.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_contact_defaut.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButton_contact_defaut.setObjectName("pushButton_contact_defaut")
```

As I said, I can't really make changes there as the code is reseted everytime I make changes to the ui file...

And here is also an extract of my main python file where I ''handle'' all the connections and logic.
I am  obviously not too familiar with Python and PyQt (or anything related to programming really!)
Is there a way to ''redefine'' the PushButton from within my code and is that the best way to approach the problem, or is there something else I am missing?

```
class NewEntry(NE_Base, NE_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent=main_window)
        self.ui = NE_Ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(0)
        self.ui.pushButton_contact_defaut.clicked.connect(self.contact_defaut)
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : Based on musicamante's answer I got it to work just fine for my app where I have 2 buttons that "fill in" different lineEdit by doing the following.

I applied .installEventFilter(self) on both pushButton and added :

```
 def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter and source == self.ui.pushButton_contact_defaut:
        self.ui.contact_text.setPlaceholderText(self.contact_base)
        self.ui.cell_text.setPlaceholderText(self.cell)
        self.ui.email_text.setPlaceholderText(self.courriel)

    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter and source == self.ui.pushButton_copy_adress:
        self.ui.street_text.setPlaceholderText(self.street)
        self.ui.city_text.setPlaceholderText(self.city)
        self.ui.postal_text.setPlaceholderText(self.postal)

    elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
        self.ui.contact_text.setPlaceholderText('')
        self.ui.cell_text.setPlaceholderText('')
        self.ui.email_text.setPlaceholderText('')
        self.ui.street_text.setPlaceholderText('')
        self.ui.city_text.setPlaceholderText('')
        self.ui.postal_text.setPlaceholderText('')

    return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

It seems a bit awkward to handle multiple pushButton this way and hopefully someone can enlighten me on that problem as well, but in the meantime, it works!

Comment: Besides subclassing each button and use a promoted widget in Designer (search in SO for related questions), using a single eventFilter is the most straightforward and common approach, so there's nothing wrong in how you implemented; you could eventually *slightly* improve the logic by grouping both `if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter` in a single if statement and check for the button instance afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an event filter on the button you want to track. An event filter is a system that "monitors" events received by the watched object and can eventually do something afterwards (including ignoring the event itself).

In your case, you'll want to check for *Enter* and *Leave* events, which are fired each time the mouse enters or leaves the widget (they are usually implemented in `enterEvent` and `leaveEvents` subclasses).

```
class NewEntry(QDialog, NE_Ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Don't do the following, is unnecessary: you already called __init__
        # QDialog.__init__(self, parent=main_window)

        self.ui = NE_Ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_contact_defaut.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Default text')
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('')
        # *always* return a bool value (meaning that the event has been acted upon
        # or not), it's common to call the base class implementation and then
        # return the result of that
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

*NEVER* edit the files generated by `pyuic`, nor start to use them as a start for your code. As you've already found out, they're cleared each time you change the ui, and it's always better to import them as modules (or use them through `uic.loadUi('somefile.ui', self)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help musicamante!
It was just what I needed and I will definitely try to read some more about eventFilter so I can better understand that last return statement...

I'm not so sure I implemented correctly for my app given that I have multiple button that need to perform different action based on the same event (see my edited question) but it works =)