# Is there any way to catch a hover event signal on a button with PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I know someone had asked this almost exact same question previously ([How to Catch Hover and Mouse Leave Signal In PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678624/how-to-catch-hover-and-mouse-leave-signal-in-pyqt5))

But I didn't really understand how or where to implement it, I just need some clarification.

Comment: Can you clarify what *clarification* you need? The linked post already clearly explains how that works: you make a subclass of a widget and implement those two methods. What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what the user did was he created a second class called button, which he used to create a button. For example, this was the code:

```py
class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        # other initializations...

    def enterEvent(self, QEvent):
        print("enter")
        pass

    def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
        print("leave")
        pass
```

Now, in order to create a button with this class, all we need to do is call the class like this:

```py
self.buttn = Button(self)
```

This creates a button using the previous class. Therefore, this is what the whole code will look like:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import PyQt5.QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
import sys

class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        # other initializations...

    def enterEvent(self, QEvent):
        print("enter")
        pass

    def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
        print("leave")
        pass

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Button")
        self.setGeometry(400,400,300,260)
        self.buttn = Button(self)
        self.buttn.setText("Button")          #text
        self.buttn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.buttn.move(100,100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```